# How to find the priority value for the unique category in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have lot of repeated categories where each category consists of different weights and i want to assign 1 weight to each unique category based on the priority.

```
mydata

  category  original_wt  predicted_wt   categorized   categorized_value
1 xxxxx      2.5          3.0            original      2.5
2 yyyyy      3.5          4.0            predicted     4.0
3 zzzzz      3.0          5.0            predicted     5.0
4 aaaaa      4.0          2.5            original      4.0
5 bbbbb      3.2          5.5            original      3.2
6 ccccc      4.6          3.5            predicted     3.5
7 xxxxx      2.5          4.0            original      2.5
8 xxxxx      4.0          5.5            predicted     5.5
9 yyyyy      2.5          4.0            predicted     4.0
10yyyyy      3.0          2.0            predicted     2.0
11aaaaa      5.0          4.5            original      5.0
```

For eg1: for a category 'xxxxx' we have three categorized values (2.5,2.5,5.5).
so from that we have to give the priority to 2.5 because it is repeated
eg2 : for a category 'yyyyy' we have three categorized values (4.0,4.0,2.0).
so from that we have to give the priority to 2.0 because it is the most repeated

But if we have only one item in category it should keep the same.
And if we have two items with two different weights we should keep high categorized value

```
Expected output:
mydata

 category  original_wt  predicted_wt   categorized   categorized_value
1 xxxxx      2.5          3.0            original      2.5
2 yyyyy      3.5          4.0            predicted     4.0
3 zzzzz      3.0          5.0            predicted     5.0
4 aaaaa      4.0          2.5            original      4.0
5 bbbbb      3.2          5.5            original      3.2
6 ccccc      4.6          3.5            predicted     3.5
7 aaaaa      5.0          4.5            original      5.0


Tried:
category_grouping_by_catg_value = mydata.groupby(['category','categorized_value']).apply(pd.DataFrame.mode).reset_index(drop=True).
```

By doing the above i am getting some random values.
How can i do this in python.

Comment: are you using a library ? pandas or other ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. I am using pandas library

Comment: then .... add tag `pandas` a your question

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing something like this:

```
df['mode'] = df.groupby('category')['categorized_value'].transform(pd.Series.mode)
df['mode'] = df.groupby('category')['mode'].transform(max)
print df.drop_duplicates(['category', 'mode']).set_index('category').sort_index()[['categorized_value', 'mode']]
```

Updated the code to select max of `categorized_value` when there are several left after doing `.mode`.

```
          categorized_value  mode
category                         
aaaaa                   4.0   5.0
bbbbb                   3.2   3.2
ccccc                   3.5   3.5
xxxxx                   2.5   2.5
yyyyy                   4.0   4.0
zzzzz                   5.0   5.0
```